# Property of group of order $231$

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group of order $231$, prove that the $11$-Sylow subgroup is in the center of $G$.

**My efforts:**
Since $o(G)=231=3\times 7\times 11$ then using third Sylow's theorem we get the following result: $N_{11}=N_{7}=1$ and $N_3=1 \ \text{or}\  7$, where $N_p$ - the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Let $H_7, \ H_{11}$ be Sylow $7$ and $11$-subgroups. Then it is easy to show that $H_7\cap H_{11}=\{e\}$ and $H_7, H_{11}$ are normal in $G$. Thus, $H_7H_{11}$ is an abelian subgroup of order $77$ in $G$.

The following inclusion is true: $Z_G\subset Z_{H_7H_{11}}=H_7H_{11}$ so $Z_G|77$ $\Rightarrow$ $|Z_G|\in \{1,7,11,77\}$.

Suppose that $N_3=1$ then $H_3$ is normal in $G$ and $H_3H_7$ is an abelian subgroup of order $21$. Applying the same method in that case we got the following options: $|Z_G|\in \{1,3,7,21\}$.
Combining this one with above we get that $|Z_G|=1, 7$. However in both cases, Sylow $11$-subgroup cannot lie in the $Z_G$.

Is this approach correct?

I have met this problem in this forum but its solution was different. I would like to complete my own solution but I am not able to do it with the case $N_3=7$.

Would be grateful for elementary solution.

Comment: Why do you consider the subgroup $H_3H_7$ at all? What information should that give you?

Comment: Elements of $G$ act on $H_{11}$ by conjugation. But $H_{11}$ is cyclic, so you know Aut($H_{11}$) and you can conclude that the homomorphism $G\to\text{ Aut}(H_{11})$ must have kernel $G$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I do not know I have never solved problems concerning Sylow's theorem. I just worked out on Sylow's theorems.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I was using $H_7H_{11}$ in order to get estimates on $Z_G$

Comment: Yes, considering $H_7H_{11}$ and $H_3H_{11}$ both make sense and give valuable information about this.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, Could you show how to approach that problem? The answer of Arnaud Mortier below showed that my efforts were false.

Comment: @RFZ answer edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following inclusion is true: $Z_G\subset Z_{H_7H_{11}}=H_7H_{11}$
>   so $Z_G|77$ $\Rightarrow$ $|Z_G|\in \{1,7,11,77\}$.

I don't understand that part. What if, say, $G$ was $\mathbb{Z}_{231}$? Then $Z_G$ would be $G$ itself and certainly not included in $Z_{H_{11}H_7}$... right?

What *is* true using your proof below is that $$(H\cap Z_G) \subset Z_H$$ whenever $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

Another approach:

$G$ acts by conjugation on $H_{11}$ because there is only one $11$-Sylow as you have proved. What you want is to show that this action is trivial.

Since $H_{11}$ is cyclic it is abelian, and therefore $H_{11}$ lies in the kernel of the action morphism $$G\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H_{11})$$

Hence this morphism factors through $G/H_{11}$. But now $G/H_{11}$ is of order $21$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(H_{11})$ is of order $10$, therefore there are no non-trivial morphisms $$G/H_{11}\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H_{11})$$
QED.

Comment: I though that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $Z_G\subset Z_H$. Let's prove it. Suppose that $z\in Z_G$ then $zx=xz$ for any $x\in G$ and the same should be true for any $x\in H$ so $z\in Z_H$. Thus, $Z_G\subset Z_H$. What's wrong?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then that would mean that $G$ is included in each of its own subgroups, which is clearly not the case. More precisely what is wrong in your argument is when you conclude "$z\in Z_H$" : for this you would need to assume that $z\in H$ first.

Comment: You make it clearer. Yes indeed the definition of center has the following form $Z_G=\{z\in G: zx=xz \ \text{for all}\  x\in G\}$. However, in my approach i have the condition that $z\in H$, right?

Comment: 1) in my book i have not met the notion of morphism and action. What do you mean when you say $G$ acts on $H_{11}$ by conjugation?

Comment: This means that there is a homomorphism $\varphi: G\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H_{11})$ given by $\varphi(g)=$ the map $h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$.

Comment: $H_{11}\subset Z_G$ is equivalent to $\varphi(g)=\operatorname{id}$ for every $g$ (indeed, $\varphi(g)=\operatorname{id}$ means $ghg^{-1}=h$ for every $h$), that is, $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: You make it quite clearer. Thanks. I accept your answer as the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72457/discussion-between-rfz-and-arnaud-mortier).