# How to show that there is an unique subgroup of order 21 in the group of order 231

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I encounter a problem of classifying the group of order $231=3\times7\times11$.

My teacher wants me to show that there is an unique subgroup of order 21 (denoted as $N_{21}$) in the group of order 231 (denoted as $G$). And obviously by Sylow Theorem there is an unique subgroup of order 11 (denoted as $N_{11}$), and teacher wants me to show that $G=N_{21}\times N_{11}$. And by the classification of group of order $pq$ (applying to the subgroup $N_{21}$), I can get the final answer that the group of order 231 has two possible structures: $C_{231}$ and $C_{11}\times(C_7\rtimes C_3)$. But I don't know how to show that the $N_{21}$ is unique.

**My attempt**

First, by the classification of $pq$ groups, the subgroup of order 21 must contain Sylow 3 and 7 subgroup.

By Sylow Theorem there is an unique subgroup of order 7, and the number of Sylow 3 subgroup is 1 or 6. And if it's 1, then by the classification of $pq$ groups, the subgroup must be $C_{21}$ determined by these two Sylow groups of 3 and 7. And if the number is 6, then I choose any of the Sylow 3 subgroup (denoted as $\langle a\rangle$ ) and the Sylow 7 subgroup (denoted as $\langle b\rangle$),then the subgroup must be $\langle a,b\mid a^3=b^7=1,aba^{-1}=b^i\rangle$, ($\bar{i}$ is the order p element in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$). But I think my proof of the latter condition is not right...

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

**p.s.:**

Afterwards, to complete the whole process, I show that $N_G(N_{21})\neq N_{21}$(the $N_{11}$ is contained in the center of $G$) thus by Lagrange I can conclude that $N_G(N_{21})=G$ thus the $N_{21}$ is normal. And  $N_{21}\cap N_{11}=1$ is kind of obvious so it's done. So I only want to know how to prove the uniqueness...

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`; also, `\mid` is better than `|` for the divider in a presentation.

Comment: Use ``**text**`` to get boldface, don't use MathJax for that.

Comment: Again, to get boldface, do **not** use `$\textbf{p.s.}:$`, use mark-up by typng `**p.s.**:`.

Comment: Note that $3\cdot 7\cdot 11$ is not of the form $pq$ for $p,q$ prime (it sounded like you do assume this). Note that $N_{11}$ is in the center, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628215/property-of-group-of-order-231).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Sorry my bad... I'll take notice of it...

Comment: @DietrichBurde: When I'm mentioning the $pq$ group, I'm discussing about the subgroup of order 21

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Sorry about the ambiguity, I've fixed it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: So you mean my proof in ‘My attempt’ section is correct? I kind of agree with you but I think I didn't do anything in this sense... I just apply the classification of the $pq$ groups... I think I didn't touch anything about the uniqueness...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is to see that there is a unique subgroup $N_7$ of order $7$ by Sylow's theorem, as the number Sylow $7$-subgroups is one of $1$, $3$, $11$ and $33$. Then any subgroup of order $21$ must contain $N_7$, so the number of subgroups of order $21$ is equal to the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G/N_7$. This is $1$, and done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have almost completed the proof.

We can easily get a subgroup whose order is 21, as you have done in your attempt. Since $N_{11}$ is normal and contained in the center, $N_G(N_{21}) \neq N_{21}$, thus  $N_G(N_{21}) = G$, i.e. $N_{21}$ is normal in $G$, then $G$ must be $N_{21} \times N_{11}$.

The uniqueness is kind of obvious, we may assume that there is another subgroup of order 21: $M_{21}$, consider $M_{21} N_{21}$, it is a subgroup since $N_{21}$ is normal, thus it’s order must divide $|G|$, so $M_{21}N_{21}$ must equal to $N_{21}$, which implies that $M_{21} = N_{21}$.

I hope my answer will be helpful to you.

Comment: The conclusion that $M_{21}$ is contained in $N_{21}$ does not follow from your calculations alone. In the Klein $4$-group $G=C_2\times C_2$, you have three subgroups, $H=C_2\times\{e\}$, $K=\{e\}\times C_2$, and $M=\{(e,e),(x,x)\}$. Then $G=H\times K$, $H\cap K$ is trivial, $M\cap K$ is trivial, but $M$ is not contained in $H$. You need to use a bit more than just that the intersections is trivial. But for example, $M_{21}N_{21}$ is a subgroup (since $N_{21}$ is normal), and has order $21^2/|M_{21}\cap N_{21}|$. The order of $G$ now forces $|M_{21}\cap N_{21}|=21$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks for your correction! I’ve corrected my answer with your help.